# RegEx for a JSON string

Tags: regex, json, sqlite

Im storing a person object as JSON in my SQLite database. The table will have few 1000 records of person objects. What i need is to query person based on the "name" attribute.

After investigation i figured out using GLOB method of SQLite to perform a RegEx kind of search in the JSON elements.

My Sample JSON is something like this.

```
{"name":"john","age":"22","father-name":"jackson"}
```

Now i want a RegEx matcher to get me all the records that matches a part of the SubString provided with the name attribute in JSON. And it should be case insensitive too.

For Ex: "ohn" search should fetch me john's record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want to go down the regex route the following will extract the record:

```
/\{"name":"\w*ohn\w*[^\}]+\}/i
```

This will match each of these:

```
{"name":"john","age":"22","father-name":"jackson"}
{"name":"john","age":"22","father-name":"johnson"}
{"name":"johnny","age":"22","father-name":"smith"}
```

but not:

```
{"name":"fred","age":"22","father-name":"hall"},
{"name":"mike","age":"22","father-name":"johnson"}
{"name":"bob","age":"22","father-name":"todd"}
```

Answer (score 3):

While you can store JSON and search against it using regexes (which are rather limited in SQLite), it does not mean you should.

Instead, you should really consider splitting your JSON into fields and storing them in normal SQLite table. Doing so will not only allow you to perform easier searches without need to painfully parse data every single time, search will be much faster too (if you add necessary indexes).

Comment: +1: Do not treat databases as disk drives. Databases are best used to store data structures, not files of strings.